# read data from Plist based on value of a Variable

Tags: ios, plist

I have a plist with multiple parent categories that are places and I want to allow the user to select the place and the only data from the child class of that plist are returned based on the value of a variable.  What is passed into the variable will be the same as the name of the parent category.  How can I retrieve different information from the plist based on the value of a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create an `NSDictionary` that holds the plist's data, and then create an array that holds the data of the variable.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
        pathForResource:@"yourPlist" ofType:@"plist"]];
NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:variable];
```

Comment: Will that still work for gathering multiple Subitems? For example I have an airport CLT and a subitem of gate which has three subitems and I need to get all three? Will this retrieve all of them?

Comment: What are the objects in the plist? Arrays, strings, numbers, etc.?

Comment: Dictionaries and strings this works to retrieve an item        NSString* name = [plist valueForKeyPath:@"aiport.B9.SitDown.Place1"];                            but I need to replace each of these with variables.